# watchkit or healthkit for getting health attributes

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, healthkit

As I saw, apple watch has different sensors: for heart pulse rate, for temperature etc. So Ive tried to look for some way to get this data from sensors to iPhone. But there is only UI mess about WatchKit, and something in HealthKit that i do not understand. So the question : can we access these sensors for receiving health data, or movement speed, or something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, WatchKit does not currently allow access to the hardware sensors on the Apple Watch.

Source: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254540?tstart=15

Comment: thank you, it was hard to find answer with right source

Comment: You can only access data from the sensors via HealthKit

Comment: @karlml From HealthKit Framework Reference: `You cannot access HealthKit from extensions (like the Today view) or from a WatchKit app.`

Comment: Kick off a request to the parent app and do it from there.

Comment: @bgilham Anyway, as said in the answer it looks like there is not public API for Apple Watch sensors yet... hope there will be in a next update

Comment: The point then is... how do manage this the already existing WatchKit apps like `Strava` and `Runtastic`? (See http://www.apple.com/watch/app-store-apps/)

Comment: Precisely. Request it from the parent iPhone app (not the extension) and send it back to the WatchKit extension. But direct access to the hardware on the Watch is impossible at it stands today.

Comment: With watchOS 2, announced earlier this week, you can access HealthKit data directly from a WatchKit extension.

Answer (score 0):

When you request parent app to fetch HealthKit data, if iPhone is locking and set a password, them you will get an error: "Protected health data is inaccessible". So, I think a health data related watch app is impossible to success submit to App Store.

Answer (score 0):

Update : it's now possible with WatchOS 2 :
https://developer.apple.com/watchos/

Sample code : https://github.com/coolioxlr/watchOS-2-heartrate